# How to select elements inside data-title with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html form like this: How can I select **Gray / Silver** from **data-title**?

```
 <div class="value">
   <div class="color-box grey-silver-color-gradient" data-title="Grey / Silver" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="" title=""></div>
</div>
```

I have wrote my code but not get the result. here

```
var data = $('.value').data('title');
console.log(data);
```

Pls help me. Thanks in advace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the `data-title` is on the child element to `.value`.

try:-

```
var data = $('.value > .color-box').data('title');
console.log(data);
```

or

```
var data = $('.color-box').data('title');
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
var data = $(".color-box.grey-silver-color-gradient").data("title");
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank so much everyone:)

Answer (score 2):

You can get attribute from tag by using `attr` from `jquery`

Example:

```
$('*[userattribute]').attr('userattribute');
```

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting one element and then expecting to get a property of another element. `$('.value')` selects the parent div of the one you want to select.

You should try this, keeping specific to a child of `$('.value')`:

```
var data = $('.value .color-box.grey-silver-color-gradient').data("title");
console.log(data);
```

or any child where data-title attribute has a value:

```
var data = $(".value [data-title!='']").data("title");
console.log(data);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o3ffptj3/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can select it by jquery method like this

```
$(selector).data('name');
```

in your case like this

```
var data = $('.value > .color-box').data('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use attr()

```
var data = $('.value div').attr('data-title');
```